# after i upload my laravel project on shared hosting cpanel i got pages errors

Tags: laravel, cpanel

i upload my laravel 5.6 project on share hosting, home, article post are showing properly but about, contacts e.t.c pages is not showing displaying this error below

ErrorException (E_WARNING)
include(/home/damschvl/damsco/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Controllers/pagesController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

i have attach screenshot below.. and php version of my hosting is 7.1 
[error display screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7kH2.png)

Comment: you have a full stacktrace and the code, should be able to find why its happening

Comment: is the class `pagesController` or `PagesController` ?